# Jmeter: Xpath to get text upto certain number of characters

Tags: jmeter

From below snippet I want to get title as My status Report(ABCDEFGH12160916)
    I have thousands of titles in my html.
    //td[@class="dealertitle"]//text() -- this gets me 
    My status Report (ABCDEFGH12160916)
    * Live, Billable, CRM *

```
 I have also tried 
//td[@class="dealertitle"]//text()//substring-before(text(),')')---                                                                                                             

Jmeter does not allow me to use substring-before. It says unknown node type
 substring-before

 Can someone please help me. 
 I want to get this text till the end - My status   Report   (ABCDEFGH12160916)

            <html>
            <head>
           <body>
          <table class="secondhead" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
           <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="title">
            My status Report (ABCDEFGH12160916)
            <span style="font-size:14pt;color:#00FF00"> * Live, Billable, CRM *                                                                          
           </span>
           </td>
           </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
          </body>
          </head>
          </html>
```

Comment: //td[@class="dealertitle"]//text()[1]

Answer (score 1):

//td[@class="dealertitle"]//text()[1]

Comment: Thank you this one worked : //td[@class="dealertitle"]/text()

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `/` in your XPath query

Your query:

```
 //td[@class="dealertitle"]//text()
```

Correct query:

```
//td[@class="dealertitle"]/text()
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Xpath Tester]

Explanation: as per [XPath Syntax article](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

> `/`  Selects from the root node
>
> `//`   Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection **no matter where they are**

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide for more details on using XPath for correlation in JMeter tests.

Comment: Dmitri - Can you please tell me how to remove spaces in text ? I want to remove extra spaces in this text. Spaces at the beginning and end -   My status   Report   (ABCDEFGH12160916)                                                              //td[@class="title"]/text()/normalize-space(.) --- this one does not work in JMeter. normalize-space is unknown node.                                                    Thank you sooo much for your help

Comment: `normalize-space(//td[@class="title"]/text())`